# CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE REFRESH MODE MANUAL from remote fails with ORA-00922

Tags: oracle-12c, multi-tenant

I'm doing some test with remote PDB cloning. Both local and remote instance are

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

The DB LINK is working, and the remote PDB exists

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$PDBS@REMOTE
WHERE NAME = 'REMOTEPDB';
```

But doing this on `sqldeveloper`

```
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE mypdb FROM REMOTEPDB@REMOTE
  REFRESH MODE MANUAL;
```

Gave me this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE mypdb FROM REMOTEPDB@REMOTE
  REFRESH MODE MANUAL
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_pdb_clone::=`

12.1 syntax:

[image]

12.2 syntax:

[image]

`pdb_refresh_mode` is available starting with version 12.2, it is not available in your version.